# WeasyPrint converting HTML TO PDF failed to generate the perfect result

Tags: html, css, django, wkhtmltopdf, weasyprint

I am working with WeasyPrint and is converting HTML to PDF. I am trying to replicate a circular percentage progress bar from HTML to PDF. The circular percentage progress bar uses transform and clip property of CSS. But the actual result is different from the expected result.

The HTML code is :

```html
   <html>
    <head>
     </head>
<style>
    body, html {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
</style>
<body>
<p>Test Page</p>
<div style="font-size: 20px;margin: 20px;position: absolute;padding: 0; width: 4.3em;height: 4.3em;background-color: white;  transform: rotate(324deg); border-radius: 50%;line-height:  5em;display: block;text-align: center;border: none;


">
    <span style="position: absolute;line-height: 5em;width: 5em;text-align: center;display: block;color: #53777A;z-index: 2;">10%</span>

    <div style="border-radius: 50%;width: 5em;height: 5em;position: absolute;">
        <div style=" position: absolute;clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em);background-color: #53777A;border-radius: 50%; width: 5em;height: 5em;"></div>

        <div style="position: absolute; clip: rect(0, 2.5em, 4em, 0); width: 5em;  height: 5em; border-radius: 50%; border: 0.45em solid #53777A; box-sizing: border-box; {% if is_pdf %}
            transform: rotate(324deg); {% else %}  transform: rotate(324deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(324deg) translateZ(0);
            -moz-transform: rotate(324deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(324deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(324deg); {% endif %}">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And after generating the pdf I am not getting the required result. 
[image]

**I have also tried wkhtmltopdf with xvfb but did not obtain the desired result.**

For all of your reference I am also attaching the code to convert the HTML to PDF using weasyprit

```
from weasyprint import HTML, CSS
from django.template.loader import get_template

template = get_template('testTemplate.html')
rendered_template = template.render({"is_pdf": 
True}).encode(encoding='UTF-8')
HTML(string=rendered_template).write_pdf('test1.pdf', stylesheets= .      
[CSS(string='@page {size:A3; margin:0px}')])
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It is just changing HTML and CSS.

Basically, I used **background-image: linear-gradient('some degree','color1 color1CoverageEnd %', 'color2 color2CoverageStart %',color2)** that helped me in achieving the perfect result.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div style="
       text-align: center;
       padding: 0">

    <div style="
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 1rem;
          width: 120px;
          height: 120px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          background-color: #ebebeb;
          background-image: linear-gradient(14.4deg, #66b8ff 50%, transparent 
          50.1%, transparent),linear-gradient(270deg, #66b8ff 50%, #ebebeb 50.1%, 
          #ebebeb);
          ">

      <span style="  font-size: 1.5rem;
             color: #8b8b8b;
             position: absolute;
             left: 50%;
             top: 50%;
             display: block;
             width: 60px;
             height: 60px;
             line-height: 60px;
             margin-left: -30px;
             margin-top: -30px;
             text-align: center;
             border-radius: 50%;
             background: #fff;
             z-index: 1;">79%</span></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

***The major change which I have done in the above code is that I had to start the color2Coverage % 0.1 percent more from the previous colorCoverageEnd ***